# Square Root of Rational

Tags: haskell

Given the following Rational:

```
Prelude> x
1 % 2
```

I tried to take its square root:

```
Prelude> sqrt x

<interactive>:14:1:
    No instance for (Floating Rational) arising from a use of `sqrt'
    In the expression: sqrt x
    In an equation for `it': it = sqrt x
```

I read this Math conversion [article](https://wiki.haskell.org/Converting_numbers#Converting_from_integers_and_between_integer_types). But I did not see how to convert between Rational and Floating.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either the [`fromRational`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromRational),

```
fromRational :: Fractional a => Rational -> a
```

or the general-purpose [`realToFrac`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:realToFrac),

```
realToFrac :: (Real a, Fractional b) => a -> b
```